# How to fix a def function run issue

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to complete an assignment for a beginning python class that asks us to write a def function that accepts a string as an argument and returns the best guess for the plural of that word. I've written out the code, but when I try to run it asks me for my input, but no matter what I type in it returns `PS C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents>` which is the location where the file is saved on my computer. It's not returning any syntax errors, so am I missing something that will trigger the def function? Please help me understand what I'm missing.

```
singular_word = input("Please enter a word to be pluralized ")
def pluralize_word(singular_word):
    if singular_word[-1] == "x" or "s" or "z":
        es_ending = singular_word[:] + "es"
        print(es_ending)
        return True
    elif singular_word[-2:] == "ch":
        ch_es_ending = singular_word[:-2] + "es"
        print(ch_es_ending)
        return 
    elif singular_word[-1] == "y":
        ies_ending = singular_word[:-1] + "ies"
        print(ies_ending)
        return
    elif singular_word[-1] == "o":
        oes_ending = singular_word[:] + "es"
        print(oes_ending)
        return
    elif singular_word[-1] == "f":
        ves_ending = singular_word[:-1] + "ves"
        print(ves_ending)
        return
    elif singular_word[-2:] == "fe":
        fe_ves_ending = singular_word[:-2] + "ves"
        print(fe_ves_ending)
        return
    else:
        print(singular_word[:] + "s")
        return
```

Comment: You _defined_ the `pluralize_word()` function, but you never _called_ it.

Comment: Tip: The `[:]` isn't needed.

Comment: Tip: It makes more sense for the function to return the plural form and let the caller print it if it so desires.

Comment: @Diyan Knd, the `PS` is part of the prompt. (It stands for PowerShell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a function named `pluralize_word`, but you never call it! You need something like

```py
pluralize_word(singular_word)
```

This needs to be placed after the definition of the function.

---

There's a second problem, and it's the following:

```py
singular_word[-1] == "x" or "s" or "z"
```

The above checks if `singular_word[-1] == "x"` is true. If it isn't, it check if `"s"` is true. *This is not the same thing as `singular_word[-1] == "s"`!* `"s"` is always true, so you never get beyond the first case (`es` is always added).

You want

```py
singular_word[-1] == "x" or singular_word[-1] == "s" or singular_word[-1] == "z"
```

Alternatively, as @John Gordon suggests, you could use the following shorter check in this situation:

```py
singular_word[-1] in "xsz"
```

Comment: Less typing: `if singular_word[-1] in "xsz":`

Comment: @John Gordon, Thanks, added.